# Error when using Timer in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i wanted to create a fake loading bar for game i'm creating and I tried to use the timer command like this:

```
def loading(time):
    print("loading "+str(time)+"%..")
t = Timer(1.0, loading(0))
t.start()
a = Timer(3.0, loading(10))
a.start()
```

But it doesn't work ( It should print loading 0% afer 1 second and loading 10% after three but it prints them all immediatly) and it gives this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "H:\Python\python\App\lib\threading.py", line 736, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "H:\Python\python\App\lib\threading.py", line 942, in run
self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Could you suggest me some solution for this problem  or other methods to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`loading(0)` calls loading right then and there.

```
t = Timer(1.0, lambda: loading(0))
```

should fix your issue. This just creates a `lambda`(anonymous function) that gets called instead, calling your function.

Comment: @user2311251 another cool thing you can do with these loading messages is use carriage returns (`\r`), they go back to the start of the line to print over it, to make loading bars